# Using keyboard-shortcuts with convertible

Tags: lenovo, wacom, stylus

I have a Lenovo L13 Yoga and *Lenovo ThinkPad Pen Pro* with Ubuntu 19.10 installed on it.
I'd like to be able to use certain keyboard shortcuts while the notebook is folded down (especially <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>prt screen</kbd>, to select an area with my stylus to screenshot).
Is there a way to achieve this, preferably other than using an on-screen keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could come up with was to create a shortcut on the sidebar, that would launch a script in Python which would send the required keystrokes that would trigger, in turn, the screenshotting function.

First, you would have to install the prerequisites: *python3-pip* - a Python package installer, and *python3* itself if you don't have it installed already.
You can do that by executing the following line in the terminal:

`sudo apt -y install python3 python3-pip`

Next step would be to install the required package, *pynput*, which will send the keystrokes. This can be done by executing the following command in the terminal:

`pip3 install pynput --user`

Next, create a script named *script.py* which sends the required keystrokes in the home folder containing the following content:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.print_screen)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)
keyboard.release(Key.print_screen)
```

The last step would be to create a shortcut which can be later added to the dock for ease of access. This can be done by creating a file in the `/usr/share/applications` folder. For the sake of this example, I will name it `shortcut.desktop` (the extension here is important). Next, add the following lines to the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=python3 /home/username/script.py  # change username to match your username
Name=Shortcut
Comment=Shortcut
```

Now, when searching for `Shortcut` in the list of applications (The lowest button on the dock) you should find your shortcut which sends these keystrokes. You can also add it to your favourites.

Comment: @user51497, was this helpful?